# Android v21 no Text in Actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-styles

I have no text in my actionbar! What's wrong with this code? There is only a blue background. I tried some different suggestions. If I try it with primary color and so on, there is a shadow which cannot be removed.

style.xml:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
</style>
<style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:background">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

This is the XML-File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/first"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
    
    
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:background="@color/blue">
        
        ...

</RelativeLayout>

<ScrollView>

    ...

</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post setting text code

Comment: in V21 there is added `ToolBar` in library. so post more code `Activity` and xml file

Comment: posted xml file! if i will post activity too it says that there is too much code in the question

Comment: You can try this: getSupportActionBar.setTitle("Title Here");getSupportActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);